# Upgrading pip on mac with an ssl certificate problem

Tags: python, pip

So I wanted to upgrade my pip after seeing the error below(1), so I followed the instructions but then the error popped up saying something was wrong with my ssl certificate and all.

All the other posts i looked at only had solutions for windows, but am a mac user. I tried downloading the file directly from pypi.python/simple/pip/ but its just sitting in my downloads folder and I didn't know where to put it to run that version instead.

Results:

**(1)You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 19.1.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.

C02HG1BBDJWT:~ Sai$ pip install --upgrade pip

Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:590) - skipping

Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg

You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 19.1.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.**

As you see I just got the ssl error message and another prompt to upgrade pip.

Answer (score 0):

`pip install --upgrade pip` installs from PyPI regardless of where you have downloaded a wheel. To install from a wheel run

```
pip install --upgrade /path/to/downloaded/pip.whl
```

Comment: Thank you for the help but I neither commands works. The second one says pip.whl is not a valid wheel filename

Comment: Put the real path to your download directory and the real name of the downloaded file.